# NFS: share with all clients except one

Tags: command-line, centos, rhel, nfs

I want to share a folder with all the network's clients except only one.
This is my current `/etc/exports` file:

```
/opt/resources     *(rw,async)
```

What should I add to prevent the client `192.168.1.24` without the need to mention all other authorized clients' addresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any NFS server that accepts negative patterns in the `exports` file.

You can use netmasks to cover several clients at once if you're listing IP addresses (you can't use wildcard patterns for IP addresses). For example the following line matches 192.168.1.* except 192.168.1.24. Yes, it's tedious.

```
/opt/resources 192.168.1.0/28(rw,async) 192.168.1.16/29(rw,async) 192.168.1.25(rw,async) 192.168.1.26/31(rw,async) 192.168.1.28/30(rw,async) 192.168.1.32/27(rw,async)  192.168.1.64/26(rw,async) 192.168.1.128/25(rw,async)
```

You can avoid cluttering the `exports` file and possibly duplication by using a [NIS netgroup](http://linux.die.net/man/5/netgroup). However, in the netgroup file you will need to list all hosts in all lists.

If you can't find a satisfactory way to describe the access lists for each exported tree, you may want to automatically generate the `hosts` or `netgroup` file.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, `NFS` does not have any option to deny a specified client (Because if client is not listed in `exports` entry, it can not access shared resource).

In your case, I think you can use `host.deny` to deny a client to access `NFS` share. Add a line to `/etc/host.deny`:

```
portmap:192.168.1.24
```

This, of course, is not a perfect solution, because the client which is listed in `/etc/host.deny` can not access to any others share resources in `NFS` server.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to use [ipset](http://ipset.netfilter.org/ipset.man.html) with iptables. ipset is available in most linux base repos.

You can make an ipset of IP addresses using, e.g.-

```
ipset create serverblacklist hash:net
ipset -A serverblacklist 192.168.1.24
```

...and add such a rule to block the ipset table 'serverblacklist' IPs-

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m set --match-set serverblacklist src -j DROP
```

Similarly, you could also make a whitelist of IPs to allow and an IPtables entry to explicitly allow them, depending on what is most expedient.